# 있어 in the middle of a sentence

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I found this sentence in my textbook:

마음에 드는 지갑이 있어 사려고 했는데 가격이 너무 비쌌다.

and its translation should be roughly:

I intended to buy my favorite wallet, but the price was to high.

My question is: what does the 있어 do in the middle of the sentence? Could this be a mistake?

Comment: It is not a mistake. `있어` in your sentence is only an abbreviation of `있어서`. Similar answer [here](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/6155/is-어려워-sometimes-the-same-as-어려워서)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sentence structure is:

> A[[마음에 드는 지갑]이 있어(서)] B[(그 지갑을) 사려고 했는데], C[가격이 너무 비쌌다].
>
> A: There was a purse I liked
>
> B: so I was about to buy (it), but
>
> C: it was too expensive.

So, 있어 in the sentence does have meaning ("there was ..."), but somehow it's missing from your translation.